# Convert JSON into Array to draw graph

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am reading values from a mysql database and export then to `JSON` via the following code

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/global.inc.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM  `chart_sales` ORDER BY id LIMIT 0 , 100";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
    // get data and store in a json array
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $ph[] = array(
            'timestamp' => $row['timestamp'],
            'ph' => $row['ph']
          );
    }

    echo json_encode($ph);
?>
```

This works like a charm and gives me the following output:

```
[{"timestamp":"1383755099000","ph":"0.50"},{"timestamp":"1383755299000","ph":"1.50"},{"timestamp":"1383755999000","ph":"1.00"}]
```

**Now my problem comes.** I want to convert the `JSON` values to an array so that I can plot the data into my graph.

This is the code that draws the graph:

```
        var d2 = [ [1383755099000, 1], [1383755299000, 1.5], [1383755999000, 1] ];          

        var sales_charts = $('#sales-charts').css({'width':'100%' , 'height':'220px'});
        $.plot("#sales-charts", [
            { label: "pH", data: d1 },
            { label: "EC", data: d2 },
        ]
```

As you can see, by now, I have inserted the array for var d2 manually. So you can see how the array is layed out. **Unfortunately I have very little experience using JSON. So please, if you know a way to read in the json file and convert it into an usable array - please let me know.**

Comment: JSON is an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation. If you've used arrays and object literals (~= assoc arrays) in JS at all, that's how you use JSON. Also **You don't have to shout, people here can read**

Answer (score 0):

This is one quick solution. Thanks for @fruityp for alerting me.

```
$json = '[{"timestamp":"1383755099000","ph":"0.50"},{"timestamp":"1383755299000","ph":"1.50"},{"timestamp":"1383755999000","ph":"1.00"}]';
    $array = json_decode($json,true);
    $temp = array();
    foreach($array as $a){
        array_push($temp,'['.$a['timestamp'].','.$a['ph'].']');
    }   
    $imp = implode(',',$temp);
    $d2 = '['.$imp.']';

    echo $d2;
```

Comment: How is this an applicable answer?

Comment: hmm even i thought so after posting the answer. Will try and edit it specific to question

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JSON object to array using this code:

```
d2 = [{"timestamp":"1383755099000","ph":"0.50"},{"timestamp":"1383755299000","ph":"1.50"},{"timestamp":"1383755999000","ph":"1.00"}];

var result = [];
for (var i in d2) {
    result[i] = [];
    result[i]['timestamp'] = d2[i].timestamp;
    result[i]['ph'] = d2[i].ph;
}
```